# Can I change the colors in FME translation log?

Tags: fme-form, color

Due to my small colorblindness I face difficulties in recognizing red text in black text.

In the FME Translation log errors are always shown in red. Is it possible to change this color (or that of the black text)? Because in this setting I can't use the software. I couldn't find it in the FME Appearance options, perhaps someone has a good solution.

Comment: workaround >An option is to copy and paste the log from the Translation Log Window into a text editor (then you can change the color/colour) which will help you read the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Have only found via FME Options> Appearance> Canvas >Current Theme > Deuteranpia

[image]

You can change font and size but not the actual colour.

Comment: Update FME replied to a tweet https://twitter.com/FMEEvangelist/status/885518440974487553 ("There's a special theme for objects, but not text. And you can change font, but not color")

Comment: An option is to copy and paste the log from the Translation Log Window into a text editor (word, notepad++) which can be modified but the translation has to complete

Comment: That would be a lot of work to export everytime I have an error, then modify the colors in a different text editor, just to find out where the error is taking place...

Comment: As Mark mentions there has been a few helpful posts on https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/47994/alerts-for-error-messages-a-sort-of-friday-challen.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unfortunately we have the deuteranopia theme, but that neglects the log file (and red text in other parts of the GUI). I've filed an enhancement request and I hope we'll improve that soon.

In the meantime, the log does get written to a file, so there's no need to copy and paste. You can just open the log file in Notepad++ with colors turned off. Or you could even set up a special color/syntax highlighting for FME log files in Notepad++ that uses a different color to red.

I've also asked the question on the [FME knowledge centre](https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/47994/alerts-for-error-messages-a-sort-of-friday-challen.html). I figure a temporary solution would be a Python shutdown script that extracts log error messages and presents them in a different way - or even just pops up a dialog saying "there was an error".

Would that help? Sadly my Python skills are fairly poor, but I'm sure someone either here or in the FME community would be able to come up with something good.

Comment: Their are a couple of Python-based suggestions on the FME knowledge centre. I won't post them here. The first one adds to the bottom of the log a list of the warnings, errors, and fatal errors, with their line numbers. The other one causes a dialog to pop up if there is an error, so that you don't have to look for errors where there aren't any. They need to be added per workspace, which is the only main drawback. But I think either of these solutions are great for anyone's workspaces, colorblind or not. I hope they are useful.